# facet_grid() causing crash

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I can not figure out what I'm missing. I keep crashing r or causing it to give very weird plots.

```
> head(vData)
           vix.Close  vstoxx vxfxi.Close       Date
2011-03-16     29.40 35.2293       35.84 2011-03-16
2011-03-17     26.37 30.6133       31.77 2011-03-17
2011-03-18     24.44 28.5337       29.31 2011-03-18
2011-03-21     20.61 25.2355       25.95 2011-03-21
2011-03-22     20.21 24.3914       24.52 2011-03-22
2011-03-23     19.17 23.9226       24.03 2011-03-23
```

The below works:

```
 p1.1<-ggplot(data = vData, aes(x = Date, y = vix.Close)) + geom_line(col= "red")
 p1.1

 p2<-p1.1 + geom_line(data = vData[!is.na(vData$vstoxx),], aes(x = Date, y = vstoxx), col="blue") 
 p2
 p3<-p2 + geom_line(data = vData[!is.na(vData$vxfxi.Close),], aes(x = Date, y = vxfxi.Close), col="green")
 p3

 p4<-p3 + labs(title = "Volatility Indexes", x = "Time", y = "Index") 
 p4
```

But this is the part that is giving me trouble:

```
 p5<- p4 + facet_grid(Date~., scales = Date)
 p5
```

Comment: try `scales = "free"` or another of the documented values

Comment: I get this or Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:vData  OR geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Comment: i don't know what you're hoping to do, but it seems unlikely that you want to use Date both as the x axis and as a facetting variable.

Answer (score 0):

I echo what baptiste said: what is it you're trying to do? The code you've provided suggests that you're trying to create a separate line chart for each date in the dataset, which doesn't make much sense. For this demonstration, I'll show you how to facet the data by year to see the correlations between the different measurements of volatility over time. If you provide more detail as a comment, I'll revisit the code.

First let's take a look at what you've already done.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)
library(lubridate)
library(reshape2)

#Generate dummy data
vData <- tibble(
  vix.Close   = rnorm(1000, mean = 12, sd = 5),
  vstoxx      = rnorm(1000, mean = 12, sd = 5),
  vxfxi.Close = rnorm(1000, mean = 12, sd = 5),
  Date = as.Date(1:1000, origin = '2011-01-01')
)

# Generate individual plots per your question
p1.1 <-
  ggplot(data = vData, aes(x = Date, y = vix.Close)) + geom_line(col = "red")
p1.1

p2 <-
  p1.1 + geom_line(data = vData[!is.na(vData$vstoxx), ], aes(x = Date, y = vstoxx), col =
                     "blue")
p2
p3 <-
  p2 + geom_line(data = vData[!is.na(vData$vxfxi.Close), ], aes(x = Date, y = vxfxi.Close), col =
                   "green")
p3

p4 <-
  p3 + labs(title = "Volatility Indexes", x = "Time", y = "Index")
p4
```

You're creating four different plots and then layering them on top of each other. This approach works here, but it's cumbersome to make changes to each of the calls to `ggplot` or if you want to add/remove variables. Let's move your data to a "long" format and simplify the `ggplot` call.

```
# Melt the data into three columns and remove NAs
vData <- melt(vData, id = "Date") %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  tbl_df()

# Create one ggplot for all three indexes
ggplot(data = vData, aes(x = Date, y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "Volatility Indexes", x = "Time", y = "Index")
```

Now back to the big problem: you shouldn't be faceting by date because that would give you a huge number of tiny unreadable line charts. There are a number of other facets that might make sense. For example, you could look at the distribution of the three indexes by year.

```
ggplot(data = vData, aes(x = variable, y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(title = "Volatility Indexes", x = "", y = "") +
  facet_grid(year(Date) ~ .)
```

So put some thought into what exactly you want to show.